# Got stuck when updating from 15.04 to 15.10, generating grub config file

Tags: boot, grub2, kernel

I tried upgrading from Ubuntu 15.04 to 15.10 through the update notification that showed up today, but it got stuck when running `dpkg --configure`.
Here are the last messages:

```
Generating grub configuration file ...
Warning: Setting GRUB_TIMEOUT to a non-zero value when GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT is set is no longer supported.
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.2.0-18-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.2.0-18-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-33-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.19.0-33-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-32-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.19.0-32-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-31-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.19.0-31-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-30-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.19.0-30-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-63-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-63-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-62-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-62-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-61-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-61-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-57-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-57-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-55-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-55-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-53-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-53-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-52-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-52-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-51-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-51-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-49-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-49-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-48-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-48-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-46-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-46-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-45-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-45-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-44-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-44-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-43-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-43-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-40-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-40-generic
```

After hours of waiting, nothing's changed.

Comment: try deleting some of those old kernels since you won't be using them anymore

Comment: @mchid I tried `dpkg --remove linux-image-3.13.0-40-generic` but got the same thing, hanging at `Found initrd image:...` again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try deleting some of the initrd images:

```
sudo rm /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-3*
sudo rm /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-4*
sudo rm /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-5*
```

and the linux images:

```
sudo rm /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-3*
sudo rm /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-4*
sudo rm /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-5*
```

Then use apt-get to purge them:

```
sudo apt-get purge linux-image-3.13.0-3* linux-image-3.13.0-4* linux-image-3.13.0-5*
```

Then, make sure the upgrade went properly by running the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

If you get no errors, run the following:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

When that is done, run:

```
cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d | grep wily
```

it should return wily.

---

**EDIT**

Because windows seems to be in a hibernated state, run the following command to fix that:

```
sudo ntfsfix /dev/sdXX
```

where sdXX is the drive and partition number of the drive partition that was "left in an unsafe state". Example sdc1.

Then, run:

```
sudo update-grub
```

and proceed.

Please post any errors.

Comment: I found something weird now. There's something like `can't find a HFS filesystem on dev sdc3` and `ufs_fill_super(): bad magic number` in `dmesg`. And I found it unable to mount any disks/partitions that are not mounted before. When I do `mount /dev/sda1 blahblahblah`, it just hangs. `ps` shows the process is in the state `D`, which stands for `uninterruptible sleeping (usually IO)` according to the document. One more thing: it says that my Windows 8 wasn't shut down properly, leaving the NTFS partition in an unsafe state.

Comment: @Cnly stick to the current issue, is that the error you got when deleting those images or when you ran apt-get?

Comment: @Cnly well yeah, you need to not hibernate windows because you won't be able to mount the windows partition if you do You are truly lucky you didn't try installing ubuntu from a disk because your windows partition would have been wiped. You should have no trouble if you disable fast boot in windows and shut down windows properly next time you login to windows BUT YOU NEED to fix ubuntu first or you may have problems with both OSs.

Comment: Removing files directly doesn't cause errors. `apt-get` won't run because of the locked `dpkg`.

Comment: @Cnly What is the exact error you get from apt-get right now when you try to run it?

Comment: `E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem. ` If I run the configure command now, it hangs again. Last message: `Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-44-generic`. And there're some processes of `/usr/lib/os-probers/50mounted-tests /dev/sda1` now. Also I tried mounting the NTFS partiton with `mount -o ro`, but it just hangs again, with no messages.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32255/discussion-between-cnly-and-mchid).

Comment: You can't mount the ntfs partition right now because of other reasons. Also run: `dpkg -P linux-image-3.13.0-44-generic`